# I want to use shared preferences in flutter, but "Object" type can not be assigned to "bool"

Tags: flutter, type-conversion, sharedpreferences

codes like this:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
sharedUtil(String key,Object dataType,Object data) async{
  SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  switch(dataType){
    case bool:
      prefs.setBool(key, data);break;
    //other types...

  }
}
```

It reports that The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool*'.
I don't know how to convert its type
thank you!!

Comment: the whole set progress has bugs like this，can it be solved when used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because `setBool` method expects a bool as a data but your data is a type of `Object`. you can use type cast operator (as) to convert the type from `Object` to `bool`.

Change your code as follows.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
sharedUtil(String key,Object dataType,Object data) async{
  SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  switch(dataType){
    case bool:

      prefs.setBool(key, data as bool);break;
    //other types...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether it is a right answer.
I add `as bool` after data

```
sharedAddData(String key,Object dataType,Object data) async{
  SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  switch(dataType){
    case bool:
      prefs.setBool(key, data as bool);break;
    case double:
      prefs.setDouble(key, data as double);break;
    case int:
      prefs.setInt(key, data as int);break;
    case String:
      prefs.setString(key, data as String);break;
    case List:
      prefs.setStringList(key, data as List<String>);break;
    default:
      prefs.setString(key, data as String);break;
  }
}
```